# Magento2 - Make zipcode requried for all countries

Tags: magento2, zipcode, administration

I want to make the zip-code fields on my website required, no matter the country the address is from. I've checked the magento settings

> Stores -> configuration -> general -> general -> country options

and under `Zip/Postal Code is Optional for`, there's always one country selected, I can't unSelect it. I have unchecked `use system value`.

Do I have to have at least one selected ?

Comment: You can always update it directly in the database table `core_config_data` where path is `general/country/optional_zip_countries`.  Just to note many countries do not have a postcode which is why this can be configured and is not always required.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thanks. We're only selling in one country so no need to worry about others for now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unselect it. For that first select any single country option there and then **click on that option with CTRL** key, after that you can save configuration and clear/flush cache using below commands

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Oh well, this was kind of a dumb question haha


Many thanks !

Comment: is that working for you ? :D

Comment: Yeah it did work :)

Comment: Okay, Buddy. ;)